# How to indicate an `&nbsp;` in xpath?

Tags: webdriver, xpath

Say we have the following HTML code. What I want is to locate to the label element whose text is **'AgendaShowCapacity (1 remaining)'** with XPath.

```
<div id="pageContent">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Agenda</legend>
    <ol class='fieldList custom' data-section='0'>
        <li class="checkboxLeft" data-id="467578" data-z="1">           
            <div class="fieldHolder1">
                <input id="467578" type="checkbox" name="467578" />
            </div>
            <div class="fieldHolder2">
                <label for="467578">AgendaShowCapacity&nbsp;(1 remaining)</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="checkboxLeft" data-id="467579" data-z="2">           
            <div class="fieldHolder1">
                <input id="467579" type="checkbox" name="467579" />
            </div>
            <div class="fieldHolder2">
                <label for="467579">AgendaHideReached</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="checkboxLeft" data-id="467580" data-z="3">           
            <div class="fieldHolder1">
                <input id="467580" type="checkbox" name="467580" />
            </div>
            <div class="fieldHolder2">
                <label for="467580">AgendaShowMessage</label>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="checkboxLeft" data-id="467584" data-z="4">           
            <div class="fieldHolder1">
                <input id="467584" type="checkbox" name="467584" />
            </div>
            <div class="fieldHolder2">
                <label for="467584">AgendaWaitlist</label>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</fieldset>
<div class="buttonGroup">
    <button type="button" name="ctl00$cph$ctlNavigation$btnAddAnother" class="button" onclick="SubmitForm(this);return false;">Add Another Person</button>
    <span class="textBetweenButtons">or</span>
    <button type="submit" name="ctl00$cph$ctlNavigation$btnContinue" class="button" onclick="SubmitForm(this);return false;">Continue</button>
</div>
```

And here is the sample C# code using selenium-webdriver to locate that element.

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
// Go to the page containing the html code above
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='pageContent']//legend/following-sibling::ol/li/div/label[text()='AgendaShowCapacity (1 remaining)']"));
// Do something to that element
```

But this doesn't work, webdriver tells me that it can't find that element using the xpath I provided. So I assumed there's some tricky points (which I can't figure out) with parentheses in that xpath expression:

```
//div[@id='pageContent']//legend/following-sibling::ol/li/div/label[text()='AgendaShowCapacity (1 remaining)']
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

**Edit 2012-10-9**
Just like user246 said, the key point is `&nbsp;` (I confirmed this once more in the original .aspx page, so I'm quite sure it is an `&nbsp;`, NOT a space).
I tried replacing the first blank with an `&nbsp;`, so the xpath changes to `//label[text()='AgendaShowCapacity&nbsp;(1 remaining)']`.
However it still doesn't work.
I edit the HTML for that label element with Firebug, replacing `&nbsp;` with a space, i.e.  changing **`<label for="467578">AgendaShowCapacity&nbsp;(1 remaining)</label>`** to **`<label for="467578">AgendaShowCapacity (1 remaining)</label>`**, this time FirePath found it using xpath `//label[text()='AgendaShowCapacity (1 remaining)']`.
So I think we can come to a conclusion that `&nbsp;` is NOT equivalent to a space in xpath.
BTW, I was verifying the xpath with FirePath in Firefox 13.0.1, but I don't think different browser would make any difference since I've also verified in Chrome21 and got the same result.
So this question has turned to **'How to indicate an `&nbsp;` in xpath'**

Comment: You might have already tried this, but try escaping the parentheses "\ (" and "\ )" (without the space)

Comment: @SuchitParikh I tried that, but it doesn't work either. Did you mean `//label[text()='AgendaShowCapacity \(1 remaining\)']`?

Comment: Please try `&amp;nbsp;` instead of `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @user246 `//label[text()='AgendaShowCapacity&amp;nbsp;(1 remaining)']` doesn't work.

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/selenium-users/BO6dtIXr8Nk

Comment: @user246 In the last post of that discussion, `//*[starts-with(translate(text(), ' ', ''), 'filter')] 

this line works! Notice: the 2nd argument in translate() function is 
nbsp inserted with Alt+0160`, what does the `Alt+0160` mean?

Comment: @Bruce Non-breaking space (nbsp) is Unicode code point 160 decimal (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm).  I think the author was describing how they coax their text editor into inserting a unicode 160 into that Xpath.

Comment: @user246 I took a look at this, [How to enter Unicode characters in Microsoft Windows](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm) It seems somewhat complex to enter unicode character. Since `starts-with` works good enough, I'll stop right here. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bruce, welcome to SQA.  The label in the element in question is `AgendaShowCapacity&nbsp;(1 remaining)`, but the label in your XPath is `AgendaShowCapacity (1 remaining)`.  I am not sure a blank and an `&nbsp;` are equivalent in an XPath.  Have you tried replacing that first blank with an `&nbsp;` in your XPath?    Another way to rule out the `&nbsp;` would be to replace `label[text()='AgendaShowCapacity (1 remaining)']` with `label[starts-with(text(),'AgendaShowCapacity')]`.

Comment: Thanks, user246. I used to ask this question on stackoverflow but got no helpful result. I found SQA filled with so many selenium webdriver questions so this must be the place I'm looking for.

Comment: I used to use //label[contains(text(), 'AgendaShowCapacity')] as a workaround, until I notice `//label[starts-with(text(), 'AgendaShowCapacity')]` in your answer, it is much more accurate to use `starts-with` than `contains`. Thank you again!

Comment: Is there any more useful xpath function besides starts-with? Can you give me some links where you get to know them? ^_^

Comment: I use http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/.